# How to apply properties over parent elements using css

Tags: html, css

I have a div with id `thdiv` with the help of that id. I need to apply css properties over div with id `fdiv`

I tried this but not able to get the desired result

```
<div id="fdiv">
 Hello
  <div id="sdiv">
   Anchor
  </div>
  <div id="thdiv">
    Hii
  </div>
 </div>


div >div {
color:red;
}
```

If I am not specifying any id then it should change the color of both the child divs. but I need to change the properties of parent div instead of child div.

Comment: There is no parent combinator in CSS as of [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/)

Comment: What is the first sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: You can't do that using `css`.

Comment: why not use just `div#fdiv { color: red; }` ?

Comment: the question is very hard to understand. The basic question of getting a parent element using CSS selectors is not possible in current CSS3. (future CSS may implement it but is not available in any browser as of yet). However, depending on exactly what you're trying to do, there may be a solution for you -- it's just that I can't understand the question well enough to work out what you mean enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to address the parent of an element only with CSS selectors. You would need some javascript to find the parent of an element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery

`$('#thdiv').parent().css({"color":"red"});`